# Node js give undefined data in nested fs.readFile call

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is my first project in nodejs. I am unable to find the cause :

[image]

```
fs.readFile("/home/shaurya/Desktop/test.txt","utf-8", 
 function(err,filedata1){
    fs.readFile(filedata1,"utf-8",function(err,filedata2){
        console.log(filedata1);
        console.log(filedata2);
    });
});
```

"/home/shaurya/Desktop/test.txt" contains the location of a file as a string. I am reading this test.txt in outer readFile call and passing the file content as parameter to inner readFile.

Content of test.txt is : /home/shaurya/Desktop/Parser.hs.

I was expecting that I will get the output as a string for console.log(filedata2) call. 
Instead I got `undefined`.

Any thoughts?

[image]

Comment: Does `err` contain anything? In either call?

Comment: Try to log err, I Bett there is an error trying to read that hs file

Comment: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/shaurya/Desktop/Parser.hs
'

Comment: but there is a valid file, I cross checked.

Comment: Your post states that `test.txt` contains `/home/shaurya/Desktop/Parser.hs.` With trailing full stop. Is that a typo? If not, that's your problem.

Comment: Ah no, looks like you have a trailing white space! `'/home/shaurya/Desktop/Parser.hs '` Or is that another typo? :/

Comment: yes , it should be /home/shaurya/Desktop/Parser.hs , sorry for that. file content does not have any typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem. In order to solve this you would you would need to append a .trim() method to the `filedata1`. Apparently sometimes text editors put an extra space or new line character after the end of the stream. This should solve your problem.

Your new code:

```
fs.readFile("/home/shaurya/Desktop/test.txt","utf-8", 
 function(err,filedata1){
    fs.readFile(filedata1.trim(),"utf-8",function(err,filedata2){
        console.log(filedata1);
        console.log(filedata2);
    });
});
```

// Please note the .trim() after `filedata1`